# WCF C# system failed to initialize with <system.serviceModel>

Tags: c#, wcf

[image]I am unable to resolve below error An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
any suggestions?

```
    using (ServiceHost host=new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService.HelloService)))
    {
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("host started @" + DateTime.Now);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    stack trace for the error is mentioned below 
    `        at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()
    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase..ctor()
    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    at HelloServiceHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\WCF\HelloService\HelloServiceHost\Program.cs:line 14
    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete call stack? Also, the app.config would be interesting.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, so your problem is elsewhere, we cannot possibly know or even begin to guess

Comment: If you run it in the debugger and inspect the exception thrown: is there an InnerException providing additional information?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a demo and found there is no problem in the code snippet, I suggest you post more details about your project.
Here is my Console project, wish it is useful to you.
**Server.**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
        {
            sh.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is ready....");

            Console.ReadLine();
            sh.Close();
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Mult(int x, int y);
}
public class MyService : IService
{

    public int Mult(int x, int y)
    {
        OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;

        Console.WriteLine(oc.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri);
        return x * y;
    }       
 }
```

**App.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServer1.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFServer1.IService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCFServer1.IService"></endpoint>
        <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5110"/>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5120"/>
        </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Result.**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.